# Store more than one calculation in a variable in Power Bi

Tags: variables, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Lets assume I have this table and the campaigns is basically a slicer.
So if a user selects `campaign 1`, it will get the total bays of `115` multiply that by the total days of `30`, and then lastly dividing the multiplication by the total days. So for that example it will be `3450` divided by `30` which will result back to `115`.

Here's where my problem is, lets say the user selects all three campaigns, I then basically need to calculate row by row the bays x days, then the grand total of that to divide it by the total days so you see the expected average should be `114.85` rather than just doing a simple average between all the bays which would give `114.83`

[image]

**Current DAX:**

```
AvgBays v3 = 
VAR bayxDays = [newAverageBays] * [newRangedDays]
VAR totalDays = SUMX(VALUES('Overview Table'[campaign]), [newRangedDays])
RETURN
    COALESCE(CALCULATE (
        DIVIDE(
            SUMX(VALUES('Overview Table'[campaign]), bayxDays),
            totalDays
        ),
        REMOVEFILTERS ('Overview Table'[No Dimension] )
    ),0)
```

I can manage to get a sum of the days because that just uses `SUMX` to iterate over the whole column and give me the total which I can store in a variable, but my question is, how would I do the row by row calculation and store that in a variable if more than one campaign has been selected. So it needs to do `115 x 30` store that in a variable, then if `campaign 2` is selected, `113.5 x 28` then store that sum into the same variable for me to be able to get the sum of all the multiplications, 9992.

Comment: I think your DAX contains a mistake. Don't store  [newAverageBays] * [newRangedDays] in a variable, use it inside SUMX explicitly. After a calculation is stored in a variable, it becomes a constant, and it's pointless to iterate over it because there is no row by row calculation.

Comment: the variable part was just an example, I basically want to do a row by row calculation based on the selected value then store that grandtotal into a variable and keep adding to that variable if more campaigns are selected if that makes sense

Comment: you're absolutely right, in the example I used it just didnt work because it was stored in a variable, when I explicitly keep it in the sumx it works, if you submit that as an answer it can get accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
AvgBays v3 = 
  var totalBayDays =
    SUMX(
      VALUES('Overview Table'[campaign]),
      [newAverageBays] * [newRangedDays]
    )

  var totalDays = 
    SUMX(
      VALUES('Overview Table'[campaign]),
      [newRangedDays]
    )

  return DIVIDE(totalBayDays, totalDays )
```